# Need a matrix such that number of chars in each element is not exceeding 5K

Tags: python-3.x, list, matrix, slice

I have list of strings
list1 = ['There', 'are two', 'goats on the bridge']

I need to find a way such that each time there are no more than 10 chars in a string. if so I need to break that.

list2 = ['There', 'are two', 'goats on ','the bridge']. 
So this should be around or about 10, somewhat what readlines would be doing.

Thanks 
-Megha

Comment: I have referred to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks but this isn't what i want to do.

Answer (score 0):

The following simply splits each element into **subelements of no more than k = 10 chars**:

```
k = 10
[x[i:i+k] for x in list1 for i in range(0, len(x), k)]
```

Result:

```
['There', 'are two', 'goats on t', 'he bridge']
```

---

If you want to **split at spaces into k = 10 plus/minus t = 2 characters**, you'll need a slightly more complex approach:

```
from functools import reduce
import operator

def split_about_k(s, k=10, t=1):
    """split s at spaces into k +/- t sized subtsrings"""
    i = 0
    while i < len(s)-k:
        j = s.rfind(' ', i+k-t, i+k+t)
        if j < 0:
            yield s[i:i+k]
            i = i + k
        else:
            yield s[i:j]
            i = j + 1
    yield s[i:]


reduce(operator.concat, [list(split_about_k(x, 10, 2)) for x in list1])
```

Result:

```
['There', 'are two', 'goats on', 'the bridge']
```

Comment: thanks for this help. As I am still newbie to this, I have another issue, that I need to make this a matrix  
[['There'] ,['are two'], ['goats on'], ['the bridge']] where each is list1[i] is less than 10.

Comment: like `[[x] for x in ['There', 'are two', 'goats on', 'the bridge']]`?